# Matlab animation on web-page

Tags: html, matlab, animation

I have a function in matlab, which takes some parameters and generates a plot. I call that function multiple times with some delay which yields an animation.
Now I want this same effect on a webpage i.e. I want to create an animation based on some inputs (which are parameters to function which generates plot), and show it on a webpage.
I want to know what is the simplest way in which it can be be done?

Comment: Can you save the plot sequence as  GIF file? That's easy enough to use on web pages.

Comment: how about https://plot.ly/MATLAB/ ?

Comment: @m.s., as far as I can tell, these plots are interactive, but not animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard format for animations on the web is (unfortunately, still) "animated GIF". You can create such a file from Matlab using [`imwrite`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/imwrite.html#btv452g-1).